# Conflicting hlsearch colours vim

Tags: vimrc

I've switched from the basic theme in terminal to a customized one. The colour issue I'm having with incompatible colours is with hlsearch. Is there a way to change the colour of the highlighted search?

I've tried searching for a solution but my search mostly brings up how to turn highlighting off after search. I would also accept a solution that underlines searches or only highlighted the first char of the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight group you are looking for is `Search`. You can see the current values with

```
:hi Search
```

You can clear the current values with either of

```
:hi clear Search
:hi Search NONE
```

How you set new values depends on the effect you want. Take a look at

```
:help 06.3
:help :highlight
```

To use just underlining for searches, execute

```
:hi Search term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline
```

Or you can change the foreground and/or background colors to suit your taste using the `:highlight` arguments and attributes described in `:help :highlight`. Those `:highlight` commands can go in your custom colorscheme file.

I don't know of a way to highlight just the first character of a search, but you can turn off search highlighting with

```
:set nohls
```

and just use the cursor to indicate where a match was found. See

```
:help hls
```

Comment: Thank you. I was doing `:h hlsearch` And had not found `:h highlight`